# HighChart to show multiple chart after drill down?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am developing a system which shows some statistical data. For this i am using HighChart (Pie).

I have tried some basic things like clicking on one Pie chart will drill down to another pie chart. But now i have to include another functionality like Clicking on one Pie chart will bring 2 new pie chart.I have searched for this in HighCharts documentation but couldn't find anything related to this.

Please help me to achieve this scenario.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment we offer drilldown to single serie, but you can catch [click event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.point.events.click) on point and then destroy chart and create new one with two series.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2qsa2e6t/2/

```
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click:function(){
                        this.series.chart.destroy();
                        $('#container').highcharts(optionsDoubleChart);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: It's better to add the code in your answer. Otherwise this isn't really an answer and should be a comment.